# Request body Object Not being Validated

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data

I have one REST API which is using a POST Call to create a record, I'm expecting certain Object to be passed in post call, if anything is missing i have to reject straight away from their only,

```
 @RequestMapping(value="/saveEssentialDetails",produces={"application/json"},method=RequestMethod.POST)
ResponseEntity<?> saveEssentialDetails(@ApiParam(value="Body Parameters")@RequestBody @Validated EssentialDetails essentialDetails, BindingResult bindingResult)throws Exception;
```

and the Essential Model class is as follow

```
    @Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@Document(collection="essentialDetails")
public class EssentialDetails {

    @NotNull
    Integer dpId;
    @Id
    @NotEmpty
    String tpId;
    @NotEmpty
    List<FamousFor> famousFor;
    @NotEmpty
    List<OpenHours> openHours;
    @NotEmpty
    Pictures uploadedImages;
    @NotEmpty
    List<FloorDescription> floorDescriptions;
    @NotEmpty
    List<Outlets> mallOutlets;

}
```

But while making a Post Call with Missing attributes i'm allowed to make an entry in MongoDB, which i don't want to persist as it's not a proper request,@Validation is not working for me, i'm using spring boot 2.0.6 with MongoDb 4.0.4,
any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks well in advance

Comment: Do you actually have a JSR303 implementation (such as hibernate-validator) on the classpath? https://spring.io/guides/gs/validating-form-input/

Comment: @AlanHay i have added the dependency of hibernate 5.4.2

Comment: I am asking about **hibernate-validator** not hibernate. You need to add your maven or gradle config to your question.

Comment: @AlanHay very much i understood what you mean by Hibernate validator and i've added
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>5.4.2.Final</version>
        </dependency> as maven dependency

Answer (score 0):

`@Validated` can be used to validate a object with a custom validation object. Example usage:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/")
public String request(@Validated(Account.ValidationStepOne.class) Account account)
```

Instead of using `@Validated` use `@Valid` which does check for the validation annotations that you are using in your entity.

Comment: thanks for prompt reply, i did tried @Valid annotation but seems not to be working,i removed the dpId attribute while making a post call, it didn't got validated and entered data in db